# add value of iterator to an arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist, iterator

I have this code:

```
for Iterator <(PhoneNumber)> i = num.iterator(); 
i.hasNext();)
 {
   PhoneNumber aNum = i.next();
   String phoneNum = aNum.getNumber();          
   Number.append(phoneNum + "\n");
 }
```

Basically what I want to do is to add the value of phoneNum into an array to that I can populate the array into a listview.

At the moment, the values show up into the textview (Number). If I change the append to setText, then it only adds the last value, and if I add a break, then it only shows the first value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand well, but i can try....

```
ArrayList<String> numList = new ArrayList<String>();
Iterator <(PhoneNumber)> i = num.iterator();
while(litr.hasNext()) {

    PhoneNumber aNum = i.next();
    litr.set(element + "+");
    String phoneNum = aNum.getNumber();    
    //this adds element into list
    numList.add(phoneNum);   
    Number.append(phoneNum + "\n");

}
```

and for notify the change you must call

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: after a little jiggling around, I got what I needed but thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[][] phoneNum = new String[num.size()][];
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
    ArrayList<String> row = arrayList.get(i);
    phoneNum [i] = row.toArray(new String[row.size()]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but it still only shows the first or last depending on whether there is a break. I want to ideally add a new row into a listview for each number it finds.